# Extjs 4.2 CSS variable for active menu item color

Tags: extjs, cmd, extjs4.2

Could it be that there is no definition for menu active item text color?????

If there is it is not intuative.

If there isnt, how can I define in my package using Sencha cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it like this at the end:

```
.#{$prefix}menu-item-active .#{$prefix}menu-item-text{
color: #273039 !important;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

then complied my package.